# php iconv translit for removing accents: not working as excepted?

Tags: php, string, unicode, utf-8, unicode-normalization

consider this simple code:

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'è');
```

it prints

```
 `e
```

instead of just

```
 e
```

do you know what I am doing wrong?

---

nothing changed after adding setlocale

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'en_US.utf8');
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'è');
```

Comment: First, this is a fundamentally evil and wrong thing to want to do.  Second, the only reasonable approach is to render your code into Unicode’s Normalization Form D formed by canonical decomposition and then remove those resulting code points with the Mark property. It won’t “fix” everything, of course: **Tschüß**

Comment: Ignore tchris, this is THE way to do it, I use it in practice. The only error you made is that the locale "subclass" is `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');` -> LC_TYPE, not _COLLATE. Tschüss.

Comment: I'm having this same problem - it is certainly not LC_TYPE... that generates an error (for me at least). I've tried LC_ALL (which is what everyone else says) - with no effect. I'm putting in the string `CŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ` and getting `CSOEZsoez"Yyenu`A'A^A~A"AAAEC`E'E^E"E`I'I^I"ID~N`O'O^O~O"OO`U'U^U"U'Yss`a'a^a~a"aaaec`e'e^e"e`i'i^i"id~n`o'o^o~o"oo`u'u^u"u'y"y`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have this standard function to return valid url strings without the invalid url characters. The magic seems to be in the line after the *//remove unwanted characters* comment.

This is taken from the Symfony framework documentation: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/08 which in turn is taken from http://php.vrana.cz/vytvoreni-pratelskeho-url.php but i don't speak Czech ;-)

```
function slugify($text)
{
  // replace non letter or digits by -
  $text = preg_replace('#[^\\pL\d]+#u', '-', $text);

  // trim
  $text = trim($text, '-');

  // transliterate
  if (function_exists('iconv'))
  {
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
  }

  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);

  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('#[^-\w]+#', '', $text);

  if (empty($text))
  {
    return 'n-a';
  }

  return $text;
}

echo slugify('é'); // --> "e"
```

Comment: I know I could do a preg_replace like that after the transliterate by iconv... I only wanted to know if the behaviour descrived in my first post is standard or iconv can transliterate "better"

Comment: Sorrry but why there are 2 backslash in the preg_replace? shouldn't be  just `[^\pL\d]` ?

Comment: What about `plƒtre francin` string where `f` does not get converted?

Answer (score 8):

cf @tchrist, with INTL php extension

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

```
preg_replace('/\pM*/u','',normalizer_normalize( $mystring, Normalizer::FORM_D));
```

**eéèêëiîïoöôuùûüaâäÅ Ἥ ŐǟǠ ǺƶƈƉųŪŧȬƀ␢ĦŁȽŦ ƀǖ** becomes

**eeeeeiiiooouuuuaaaA Η OaA AƶƈƉuUŧOƀ␢ĦŁȽŦ ƀu**

---

As tchrist emphasises, not all unicode characters are considered decomposable:

extract from Unicode charts:

U0080.pdf

> 00CF Ï LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS
>
> ≡ 0049 I  0308 ¨
>
> NB this symbol « ≡ » indicate an available decomposition
>
> 00D0 Ð LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH
>
> → 00F0 ð  latin small letter eth
>
> → 0110 Đ  latin capital letter d with stroke
>
> → 0189 Ɖ  latin capital letter african d

no decomposition available, IMHO strangely (we could consider ASCII letter D as an acceptable equivalent).

U0100.pdf

> 0110 Đ LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE
>
> → 00D0 Ð  latin capital letter eth
>
> → 0111 đ  latin small letter d with stroke
>
> → 0189 Ɖ  latin capital letter african d

even stranger: this one is identified as LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D (with stroke), but not decomposable as such! Perhaps a cooler solution should be to get the unicode description of each char, and compare it with the description of each ascii char (and replace accordingly). Anyone? ;-]

cf http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, on vanilla PHP7.2.

Answer (score 2):

It happen with me with pure iconv without php. The Trick was to set LANG environment value to en_US.UTF-8 (it was hu_HU.UTF-8 before, in my case). After it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When doing transliteration, you have to make sure that your LC_COLLATE is properly set, otherwise the default POSIX will be used.

Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: same result as before with setlocale, (see first post)

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to say "nothing", although this is a little outside my expertise. PHP's iconv() is notorious, and the inspiration for many workarounds, including

- dropping to the system's iconv
  utility (Unix & Linux)
- crafting a lookup table
- replacing all accented characters
  with an ASCII equivalent as kind of a
  preprocessing stage
- setting LC_COLLATE (which doesn't
  seem to work for everyone)
- use htmlentities() instead of iconv()

Read the comments for [iconv() documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for more inspiration. (Or commiseration. Too close to call.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the standard way to handle this is with a "removing accents" function which you can find in library's like [flourish](http://flourishlib.com/) or CMS's like [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org). Iconv seems to be unable to translate accents (and rightly so) since this isn't a good idea for anything other than URL slugs.

Answer (score -1):

It seem that it depend of the php version...

---

### TestCase #1

```
php -version
```

**PHP 7.0.0RC8** (cli) (built: Nov 25 2015 12:36:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

```
php -r "var_dump(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'è'));"

string(2) "`e"
```

---

### TestCase #2

```
php -version
```

**PHP 7.0.8-1~dotdeb+8.1** (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-1~dotdeb+8.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

```
php -r "var_dump(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'è'));"

string(1) "e"
```