# Sort array of UTF-8 strings so that un/accented letters are treated equally

Tags: php, string, sorting, utf-8, comparison

I'm trying to compare two string lets say `Émilie` and `Zoey`. Well `E` comes before `Z` but on the ASCII chart `Z` comes before `É` so a normal `if ( str1 > str2 )` won't work.

I tried with `if (strcmp(str1,str2) > 0)`, but that still doesn't work. So I'm looking into a native way to compare string with UTF-8 characters.

Comment: I specify 'native way' cause I already tried to replace every `é è ê ȩ ë` with `e` but it cause some problem when I forget some characters

Comment: Unsolicited side note: `<` and `strcmp` both compare lexicographically. They're basically different wrappers around the same algorithm.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**

This answer is meant for situations where it's not possible to run/install the 'intl' extension, and only sorts strings by *replacing accented characters to non-accented characters*. ***To sort accented characters according to a specific locale, using a [Collator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) is a better approach*** -- see the other answer to this question for more information.

**Sorting by non-accented characters in PHP 5.2**

You may try converting both strings to ASCII using iconv() and the //TRANSLIT option to get rid of accented characters;

```
$str1 = iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $str1);
```

Then do the comparison

See the documentation here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

[updated, in response to @Esailija's remark]
I overlooked the problem of //TRANSLIT translating accented characters in unexpected ways. This problem is mentioned in this question: [php iconv translit for removing accents: not working as excepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910627/php-iconv-translit-for-removing-accents-not-working-as-excepted)

To make the 'iconv()' approach work, I've added a code sample below that strips all non-word characters from the resulting string using preg_replace().

```
<?php

setLocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');

$names = array(
   'Zoey and another (word) ',
   'Émilie and another word',
   'Amber',
);


$converted = array();

foreach($names as $name) {
    $converted[] = preg_replace('#[^\w\s]+#', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $name));
}

sort($converted);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($converted);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => Amber
//     [1] => Emilie and another word
//     [2] => Zoey and another word 
// )
```

Comment: Yup, iconv() is native. You may need to use set_locale() first, you'll find some examples in the comments below the documentation page

Comment: @PLAudet -1 This is misleading because of the example. The result string is `'Emilie`, so yes, it will appear before `Z` but it will also appear before `A`. Please use a collator from  http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php

Comment: @Esailija I stand corrected, you're right about the quote in front of Emilie, hadn't realized that //TRANSLIT did this. I agree that the 'Collator' approach is the official way to do it, but OP stated that he didn't have the option to use that. I added a fix to my answer by preg_replacing non-word characters from the string

Comment: @thaJeztah only because he thinks it requires php 5.3, however it can be used with 5.2 which is why I linked the requirements page so he can read it more carefully this time ;P

Comment: @Esailija I've added your information to the answer fab provided so that the OP is able to make a decision which approach to take. My edit is currently waiting for review.

Answer (score 17):

There is no native way to do this, however a PECL extension: http://php.net/manual/de/class.collator.php

```
$c = new Collator('fr_FR');
if ($c->compare('Émily', 'Zoey') < 0) { echo 'Émily < Zoey'; }
```

Comment: Seems a good solution but the client's server is on php 5.2, well if there's no native way i'll rollback to the massive string replace solution :(

Comment: Then better convert them instead of replacing characters manually, the `iconv` solution seems appropiate.

Comment: This is built-in as of PHP 5.3. So you can use e.g. `$collator = collator_create('pl_PL');` and then use a compare function `return collator_compare($collator, $a, $b);`.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/collator.compare.php

Answer (score 1):

I recomend to use the `usort` function, to avoid modifying the values, and still compare them correctly.

Example:

```
<?php

setLocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');

$names = [
   'Zoey and another (word)',
   'Émilie and another word',
   'Amber'
];

function compare(string $a, string $b) {
    $a = preg_replace('#[^\w\s]+#', '', iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $a));
    $b = preg_replace('#[^\w\s]+#', '', iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $b));

    return strcmp($a, $b);
}

usort($names, 'compare');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($names);
echo '</pre>';
```

with result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Amber"
    [1] => "Émilie and another word"
    [2] => "Zoey and another (word)" 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly modifying values is not good as a general use technique. Also, it is a bad idea (inefficient) to perform string mutations (x2) on each iteration of a sorting function.

Improving the script efficiency of Marqitos's answer, make singular mapped calls of `iconv()` and sort the original array by that mutated copy.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cki26))

```
setLocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');

$names = [
   'Zoey and another (word)',
   'Émilie and another word',
   'Amber'
];

array_multisort(
    array_map(fn($v) => iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $v), $names),
    $names
);

var_export($names);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Amber',
  1 => 'Émilie and another word',
  2 => 'Zoey and another (word)',
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's something that works for me although I'm not sure if it will serve the purpose of comparing the special characters other languages have.

I'm just using the `mb_strpos` function and looking at the results. I guess that would be as close as you can get to a native comparing of UTF8 strings:

```
if (mb_strpos(mb_strtolower($search_in), $search_for) !== false) {
    //do stuff
}
```