# non latin strings compersion with diffrent encode

Tags: php, character-encoding, arabic

I have a directory "Dir1" that contains n directories which were named with non latin characters
I got the names of these directories by `scandir`

```
$allDirs =  scandir( ARCHIVE_DIR) ;
foreach( $allDirs as $dir){.....}
```

and I want to comapre each dir name with strings I have
but the comapre return false
I tried

```
 if(  $dir  ==  "أخبار"   )
```

AND

```
if( utf8_encode ( $dir  ) === utf8_encode( "أخبار" )  )
```

AND

```
strcmp ( $dir , "أخبار" )
```

AND

```
mb_strpos( $dir , "أخبار" )
```

When I tried
 `mb_detect_encoding($dir)`

```
mb_detect_encoding("أخبار")
```

both of them returned  utf-8
I'm not sure what is the issue here 
when I tried to print them to log via

```
file_put_contents( "n.log" ,$dir."--"."أخبار" ."\r\n", FILE_APPEND  ) ;
```

it print identical strings !!!!
but the compare always fail
how to fix that ?

Comment: I'm not certain how you used `mb_strpos`, but I hope you checked if it is `!==FALSE`. I'm not really familiar with arabic but are there possibly characters that look the same? but can be encoded with a different utf-8 string?

Comment: yes, I checked if it is !==FALSE but no luck

Comment: I'd probably output the `bin2hex` of both strings, to check if they really are the same ...

Comment: I tried that didn't work also

Comment: what I said: *output* those two bin2hex ... so you can actually *see* the bytes the strings are made up of. Because my theory would say, that those two strings you're comparing *look* the same visually but aren't the same binary (or those comparison shenanigans wouldn't make any sense anyway) Many sophisticated languages with diacritics and stuff use composition of characters, like adding some accent to another character. if you have multiple of those on one char, their *order* matters as well, when just comparing

Comment: p.s.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655092/comparing-utf-8-string (look at that collator, probably) and sift through the answers. they might help.

Comment: yes when I put each string to file one of them was 5 Bytes and the other was 10 Bytes. but both showing the same word

Comment: at least now you know that they in fact are different. collation could help, or `utf8_encode`ing only the - i guess here - 5 bytes one ... possibly helps. However, this is a dirty hack either way. you should avoid magic constants in your code ...