# How to truncate non-ascii characters from string using PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a following string as a Filename

`$string = 'recyclage plétre francin.jpg';`

and tried with following code

```
echo preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9|^.]/i', '_', iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT",$string));
```

as there is a special (non-ascii) character in filename it creates junk character while working with file uploading using PHP.

What I want is that replace any unicode (non-ascii) character with specific Ascii character.
I want to keep all supported Ascii characters and remove non-ascii characters. I also want to keep `/` or `\` slashes because of directory separators in filename where a root path will be given.

**Edit:** (below is not solved)

I am having a issue with `recyclage plƒtre francin.JPG` please the `f` character which displays output like `recyclage pl` and it had truncated `.JPG`. Actually file name was `recyclage plâtre francin` and when I was debugging it has shown `recyclage plƒtre francin.JPG` and rest is written just after that. Any Idea?

When I am trying to convert `tri et recyclage du plâtre` but when at the reading it shows `tri et recyclage du plÃ¢tre` and after conversion it shows `tri et recyclage du pl^atre`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `utf8_encode($string)`?

Comment: Yes. But no luck. I tried with all character conversions from PHP functions and finally decided to replace unicode characters and just replace with specific character like `_`

Comment: oh i misunderstood, you want to convert it TO ascii

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497685/how-do-i-detect-non-ascii-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution to my question. Finally I could able to see the conversion. Some Unicode characters are replaced with some Ascii characters. But after all everything is now working fine.

```
function toASCII($str)
{
    $accent   = 'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕƒ';
    $noaccent = 'SOZsozYYuaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRra';
    $string = strtr(utf8_decode($string),utf8_decode($accent),$noaccent);
    return strtr($string, $accent, $noaccent);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use the `TRANSLIT` modifier, it replaces all characters which can't be displayed in the target encoding. Since é  *can* be represented in ISO-8859-1 it is encoded as ANSI-Code `0xE9`.

I guess you want something like that:

```
$string = 'recyclage plétre francin.jpg';
echo iconv("UTF-8","ASCII//TRANSLIT",$string);
```

The result with that `iconv`-call is: `recyclage pletre francin.jpg`

Comment: I am having a issue with `recyclage plƒtre francin.JPG` please the `f` character which displays output like `recyclage pl` and it had truncated `.JPG`. Actually file name was `recyclage plâtre francin` and when I was debugging it has shown `recyclage plƒtre francin.JPG` and rest is written just after that. Any Idea?

Comment: When I am trying to convert `tri et recyclage du plâtre` but when at the reading it shows `tri et recyclage du plÃ¢tre` and after conversion it shows `tri et recyclage du pl^atre`.

Comment: Hmm apparently ["not all characters are decomposable"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11867974/855532). Which means that some characters are translated into non-ASCII-characters. That means you could either use a regex to filter or map any unwanted characters (of course the "mapping" is probably a bigger/complicated task).

Answer (score 1):

```
Check this code 

<?php

$string = 'recyclage plétre francin.jpg';
$str = preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]/', '', $string);
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Worked perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple one that will remove all chars except a-z, 0-9 or whitespace.

```
// Remove all characters that are not the separator, a-z, 0-9, or whitespace
$string = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote('-').'a-z0-_9\s]+!', '', strtolower($string));
// Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
$string = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote('-').'\s]+!u', '-', $string);
```