# Iconv suddenly returns question marks, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, iconv

The iconv code that I have, worked yesterday perfectly. Today it suddenly shows those question marks at the parts that should be translated(�).

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $title = (iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $title));
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $description = (iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $description));
    $datedag = date('d', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    $datemaand = date('F', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    $datejaar = date('Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<div style="border:1px solid black;background-color:#d90000;"><p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Geplaatst op '.$datedag.' '.$datemaand.', '.$datejaar.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p></div><br />';
```

Now, I didnt add the setlocale until the question marks showed up, but it had no succes.

**Question**: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like an encoding problem. Looks like you're going to `ISO-8859-1`. Perhaps your page has a header saying it's `UTF-8`?

Comment: I'd really have no idea, but yesterday it worked fine, and I didn't change the code.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

although my language was Czech. Credit to [Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405498/2474687)

Comment: you can also force default language from outside of PHP before excution in case of commandline script `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me that the encoding was wrong since I updated PHP to 5.6. This version sets the default charset to UTF-8 and transports this via the HTTP-Header, even though you set your charset to ISO-8859-1 in your HTML meta-tag.

Consider using UTF-8 at all or overrule the default charset by including the following line at the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('default_charset', '');
```

You can also change the default charset in your `php.ini` as well.