# Symfony2 replacing spanish letters with english

Tags: php, symfony, preg-replace

I am creating a file reader and I need to design it the way, so that the spanish letters would be changed to english otherwise it wont work...

It seems easy enough however the letters are just not replacing..

```
$header = $this->file->current();

//        replace spanish characters with english

        $spanishChars = array('ó', 'á', 'í', 'é', 'ú', 'ñ', 'Ó', 'Á', 'Í', 'É', 'Ú', 'Ñ');
        $englishChars = array('o', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'u', 'n', 'O', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'U', 'N');

        $headers = str_replace($spanishChars, $englishChars, $header);

        echo var_dump($headers); die;
```

The output I get is the same(the letter is not replaced):

```
0 => string 'id,categ�ria,nombre,descripcion,PVP sin iva,PVD,stock,EAN13,estado,referencia,foto' (length=82)
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Because the spanish letter is converted to a ? it probably is the reason why it cant convert?

Becauce is I do:

```
$headers = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $header);
```

this completely removes the spanish letter
and

```
$headers = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $header);
```

says that `iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`

Any other ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910627/php-iconv-translit-for-removing-accents-not-working-as-excepted

Answer (score 0):

I use a js script I got from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120918093154/http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics)

which is very comprehensive you'd only need the Spanish ones